# how to use swiper properties to change to conditionally change tailwind css

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css, swiper.js

I'm trying to use a swiper property to conditonally change css using tailwind; Something like the code below but of course, it doesn't work. How could I go about accomplishing this? Thanks in advance.

```
import {useEffect} from 'react'    

function Component(){
  const [slideBegin, setSlideBegin] = useState();
  const [swiper, setSwiper] = useState();

    useEffect(()=>{
    if(swiper){
        setSlideBegin(swiper.isBeginning)
        }
     })

  return(

   <Swiper
     onSwiper={(swiper) => setSwiper(swiper)}
   >
     <svg className={`${slideBegin?'fill-[#ffc000]':'fill-red-600'}`}></svg>
   </Swiper>
  )
 }
export default Component
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a solution using useSwiper hook from the swiper react documentation. I created a component that housed the elements I want to change based on swiper property (a previous and next buttons component in which I want styles updated on in this case) and used event functions to do it. Then in you import this component into your main component that has the actual swiper wrapper.

Main Component:

```
<Swiper>
    <ButtonsComponent>
<Swiper/>
```

and what inside that button component would look like:

```
import { useSwiper } from "swiper/react";
import { useRef } from "react";
import useIsomorphicLayoutEffect from "use-isomorphic-layout-effect";


const SwiperButtons = () => {

        const swiper = useSwiper()
        const prevEl = useRef()
        const nextEl = useRef()

const prevFunc = ()=>{

    swiper.slidePrev()
    if(swiper.isBeginning==true && swiper.isEnd==false){
        prevEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = 'none'
        nextEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = '#FFC000'
    }else if(swiper.isEnd==true && swiper.isBeginning==false){
        nextEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = 'none'
        prevEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = '#FFC000'
    }else{
        prevEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = '#FFC000'
        nextEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = '#FFC000'
    }
}

const nextFunc = ()=>{

    swiper.slideNext()
    if(swiper.isBeginning==true && swiper.isEnd==false){
        prevEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = 'none'
        nextEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = '#FFC000'
    }else if(swiper.isEnd==true && swiper.isBeginning==false){
        nextEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = 'none'
        prevEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = '#FFC000'
    }else{
        prevEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = '#FFC000'
        nextEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = '#FFC000'
    }
}

useIsomorphicLayoutEffect(()=>{

    if(swiper.isBeginning==true && swiper.isEnd==false){
        prevEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = 'none'
        nextEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = '#FFC000'
    }else if(swiper.isEnd==true && swiper.isBeginning==false){
        nextEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = 'none'
        prevEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = '#FFC000'
    }else{
        prevEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = '#FFC000'
        nextEl.current.querySelector('.rect').style.fill = '#FFC000'
    }

}, [swiper])


return (
        <div className='flex justify-between mb-6 ml-12 w-[calc(100vw*0.15)]'>

            <button onClick={prevFunc}>
                <svg ref={prevEl} <rect className="rect" x="2.88" y=".72" width="20.82" height="34.24"/></svg>
            </button>

            <button onClick={nextFunc}>
                    <svg ref={nextEl} <rect className="rect" x=".72" y=".72" width="20.82" height="34.24"/></svg>
            </button>

        </div>
)
};

export default SwiperButtons
```

Comment: Also just now realizing that swiper has an on method that allows us to call events on the swiper instance; So, knowing this you can simply use the onSwiper property of the <Swiper> component and use the callbacks in there.

`onSwiper={(swiper)=>{swiper.on('slideChange',( )=>{document.querySelector('.text').innerHTML = `${swiper.isBeginning}`})`